# Getting a row number of a row which is associated with a specific group of rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in MySQL database as shown in the following [snap shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5CGj.png).

[image]

I need to obtain a current row number based on `rating_id` (primary key) given **in each group of products**.

Currently the following SQL obtains a row number based on `rating_id` from all rows in the table.

```
SELECT rownum 
FROM   (SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rownum, 
               tbl.rating_id 
        FROM   rating tbl, 
               (SELECT @rownum := 0)t 
        ORDER  BY tbl.rating_id DESC)t 
WHERE  rating_id = ?
```

How to restrict this query to a specific group of products (`prod_id`)?

In other words, how to get a row number from a group of rows which is specific a particular product (`prod_id`)?

Comment: add `AND prod_id BETWEEN x AND y` to your outer select statement?

Comment: Either add WHERE in the inner query or add AND in the outer query (and add `prod_id` in the SELECT portion).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you need to count each group of PROD_ID separately. In this case you should add one more user defined variable to store previous PROD_ID and reset `@rownum` when new PROD_ID group starts.

```
SELECT rownum,rating_id,prod_id 
FROM   (SELECT if(prod_id=@prev_prod,@rownum := @rownum + 1,@rownum:=1)
               AS rownum, 
               tbl.rating_id,
               tbl.prod_id,
               @prev_prod:=prod_id  
        FROM   rating tbl, 
               (SELECT @rownum := 1,
                       @prev_prod:=NULL)t 
        ORDER  BY tbl.prod_id)t 
WHERE  rating_id = ?
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/02eff/4)</kbd>